# Why are there two 'willSelectRowAtIndexPath'?

Tags: swift, uitableview

[image]

In the TableViewController class, when i go to select the method for "willSelectRowAtIndexPath", i see that there are two of them available. Are they both the same thing?

See attached screenshot.

I'm using Xcode 7.0

Comment: [bugreport@apple.com](https://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: in the latest Beta every function is duplicate as well, one with an exclamation mark after "tableview" the other without. Is a bug. I had it with a function of my own earlier today, failed to recreate it.